# Sending a DXL command to IBM Doors From a C# application over TCP/IP

Tags: c#, ibm-doors

I am trying to send a DXL command to IBM DOORS over TCP/IP.
I managed to do it. But in that case, I need to start the TCP/IP server from DXL Interaction window using the command `evalTop_ initDXLServer server portNumber`. Is there any way to do it from the C# application itself ?

Answer (score 1):

You could start your own DOORS client from your C# application, either in batch mode (`doors.exe... -b path/to/program.dxl`) or in GUI mode (`-dxl "#include <path/to/program.dxl>"`). See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ermd/9.7.2?topic=client-command-line-switches-doors

Comment: Do you think two way communication is possible between DOORS and my Console Application over TCP/IP ?

Comment: Generally, we found that communication using plain files is way more stable than two way TCP/IP communication. I.e. you would send a DXL script to DOORS and that script returns the things it did (or the values it calculated) in a file (the file name would be temporary, and it would be a parameter given to the file or coded into the file). This gives you all needed ways to communicate data, infos, warnings, errors, return codes.

Comment: If you also plan that communication is triggered from DOORS itself, you should perhaps install triggers on DB, project or module level, that e.g. POST SAVE will send some information to a defined file that you watch constantly

Comment: But DXL seems very slow. So what you suggests is, write response from DOORS to a file and read that file from my C# application ? But if the DXL execution time is long, how do I warn the user ?

Comment: DXL is not really slow per se. There are some pitfalls to avoid: cout is faster than print, don't forget to free what you allocated to avoid out of memory issues, don't overuse strings, prefer Buffers, avoid OLE.... But of course what you do with the data might take some time (e.g. copying thousands of objects to another module, reading many modules at the same time etc etc).Your DXL script could open the output file in append mode, write a message and flush the stream after every message. This way you could send messages "finished 10%" to the calling user, perhaps in a 2nd output status file